# errno advantage over java exceptions

Tags: java, c++, c

trying to figure out the advantage of errno.

What advantage(s) do the C approaches (using errno or return values) to denoting errors have over the Java system based on exceptions?

Comment: It's like asking whether you should walk to work or take the subway.

Comment: Generally, none. Disadvantages: forgetting to check error code results, mixed error-free and error-full code paths, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no advantages except simplicity of implementation -- but only for single-threaded code.  `errno` dates from before exceptions existed in any popular language.

**EDIT**: Nowadays `errno` actually evaluates to a macro that extracts a per-thread error state, so it's safe to use in multithreaded code (thanks Jesus Ramos and Dietrich Epp).

Comment: Actually errno is defined percpu so it's actually thread safe.

Comment: @JesusRamos: Do you mean per thread?  That would make it thread safe in the most important way.

Comment: It is per-thread.  It doesn't look like it, but `errno` is actually a macro, and it defines to something like `#define errno *get_per_thread_errno()`.  Note that most of the newer APIs avoid using `errno` at all -- like `gethostbyname()` and POSIX threads.